# Excluding lists of hosts from SGE job submission

Tags: bash, shell, sungridengine

I am using a cluster running SGE 8.1.9. Some nodes on the server are broken and some are working. I have a list of node host-names which are working OK, so I want to submit my array job to those nodes only.

I have successfully submitted jobs to a single node which works:

```
qsub -t 5:18 -l h=nodeA myScipt.sh
```

However, I want to submit my jobs to a list of working nodes, e.g.:

```
qsub -t 5:18 -l h=nodeA,nodeB,nodeC myScipt.sh
```

But this throws:

```
Unable to run job: unknown resource "nodeB"
Exiting.
```

What is the correct syntax to submit your array job to a list of nodes if you have their hostnames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured you can include the flag:

```
#$ -l h=!(nodeA|nodeB)
```